# Real objecs instead of drawing in canvas

Tags: java, swing, graph

This is a somewhat general question, thus I'm not quite sure if it fits here.

I'm working on a project right now where we generate graphs, which then will be displayed in a GUI.
The GUI will be developed using Swing.

Now I'm unsure what best to use for drawing the graph. I could certainly use the Canvas class, but then again modifying the drawn objects will be difficult. A better way would be to add real objects into the canvas or the GUI instead of drawing it.

Can you guys recommend any good library or Java framework to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Just to clarify: With graphs I mean graphs as in graph theory. Vertices and edges. So adding real vertex objects to the GUI, which then again can be selected and everything.

Comment: Don't use Canvas, an AWT class, if you're creating a Swing GUI. Stick with Swing such as JPanel or JComponent. For pure graphing, look at using JFreeChart or something similar. It can create JPanels that have graphs on them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend using this one: [Netbeans Visual Library](http://platform.netbeans.org/graph/). It's developed as a part of the Netbeans RCP, but can be used without it. It is a highly abstract API for building visual components, with many already implemented. It provides a canvas, objects which you can build and display on canvas, simple map (overview) to navigate big container with ease and some generic layout algorithms.

Here is [a tutorial](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-visual_library.html)